# Beginning with Python: Calculating time alive, and time til death

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am relatively new to Python and coding in general, so please bear with me if it takes me time trying to grasp concepts put forward to me

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
age = int(raw_input("What is your age?"))
death_date = int(raw_input("When do you think you will die?"))

a = 8760 * age
#8760 hours is one year(365) multiplied by 24
b = 525600 * age
#525600 equals one year multiplied by 1440 minutes in a day
c = 31536000 * age
#31536000 equals one year multiplied by 86400 seconds in a day

feelsbadman = death_date - age
d = 8760 * feelsbadman
e = 525600 * feelsbadman
f = 31536000 * feelsbadman

print(name, "you have lived for", a, "hours", b, "minutes", c, "seconds")
print("You are going to die in", d, "hours", e, "minutes", f, "seconds")
```

So basically, I keep getting a SyntaxError on the variable "a", for reasons I don't understand.

Previously, this SyntaxError was not occurring however upon the addition of the "feelsbadman" variable, it began to appear. I cannot find where I have gone wrong, and I'm fairly certain it's a minor discrepancy that I haven't spotted, but I would be grateful if someone could spot it for me. Sorry if this seems rather rude

EDIT: Image removed, this is hopefully sufficient

Comment: please post you code as text instead of image  !

Comment: Please post your code instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the closing parenthesis for `int()` in the declaration of variable `death_date`:

```
death_date = int(raw_input(...))
#                              ^ Here
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry if this was a bit of a messy post.